# Help me find all sequences of real numbers that meet the following conditions

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, real-numbers

For every integer $n$ where $n \geq 4$, find all such sequences of real numbers $a_1, a_2,..., a_n$, that: $$a_{i+1}^2 + a_{i+2}^2 + 2a_{i}a_{i+3} \leq 0$$ for every $$i=1,2,3,...,n$$ where $a_{n+t}=a_t$ for $t \in \lbrace 1,2,3 \rbrace$

I analyzed this problem in my mind and I know that there must be some sort of "circle" for which the conditions are met. The thing is I've no idea how to write it cleverly on paper.